# Syntax - Why do kubernetes labels get removed with a "-"?

Tags: kubernetes, label

I am wondering if anybody knows the logical reasoning behind the syntax to remove a label in Kubernetes?

If I have a Pod named **nginx** labeled **env=testing**, I know that I can remove the label like so:

`kubectl label pod nginx env-`

But **why** do we need to use a `-`, not have some other command or a `--remove` flag to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a design decision.

You can check the implementation here:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/cmd/label/label.go#L418

```golang
    func parseLabels(spec []string) (map[string]string, []string, error) {
        labels := map[string]string{}
        var remove []string
        for _, labelSpec := range spec {
            if strings.Contains(labelSpec, "=") {
                parts := strings.Split(labelSpec, "=")
                if len(parts) != 2 {
                    return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid label spec: %v", labelSpec)
                }
                if errs := validation.IsValidLabelValue(parts[1]); len(errs) != 0 {
                    return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid label value: %q: %s", labelSpec, strings.Join(errs, ";"))
                }
                labels[parts[0]] = parts[1]
            } else if strings.HasSuffix(labelSpec, "-") {
                remove = append(remove, labelSpec[:len(labelSpec)-1])
            } else {
                return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("unknown label spec: %v", labelSpec)
            }
        }
        for _, removeLabel := range remove {
            if _, found := labels[removeLabel]; found {
                return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("can not both modify and remove a label in the same command")
            }
        }
        return labels, remove, nil
    }
```